# reasons for a dd image of an almost-empty drive not be small after gzip

Tags: filesystems, dd

i just cleaned a 50GB partition with `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda1`

then added some data to it (actually installed a linux distro) some 3Gb on ext4.

and decided to make a image.

`dd if=/dev/sda1 | gzip -9 > sda1.dd.gz`

and to my surprise, that file has 45GB!

my thinking would be that the this file would have some 4GB as most of the size would be tailing zeros that `gzip` would take care of.

where am I wrong? anyway to check how back the fragmentation is after the add-data step?

Also, if it is fragmentation, any way to fix it? i'm now writing /dev/zero to a file until the drive is full...

Comment: I guess if you enabled full-disk encryption, that'd explain it. Or maybe if you ran badblocks (in write-destructive mode) as part of making the filesystems.

Comment: turned out that the install, for some reason, scattered data all over the disk. I redid the `cat /dev/zero > /mounted_drive/zero` _after the install_ and then removed the file and redid the `dd`, turned out to be a 1.3Gb file after gzip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From OP's comment:

> Turned out that the install, for some reason, scattered data all over the disk. I redid the `cat /dev/zero > /mounted_drive/zero` after the install and then removed the file and redid the `dd`, turned out to be a 1.3Gb file after `gzip`.

With this, the question is effectively answered (and, as a side-effect, removed from Unanswered Questions queue).

Comment: i think i wrote that as an answer and the site moved up to a comment because it was too short..? it does that sometimes. thanks